# SAML with Open Search (AWS) giving error "Error while validating SAML response in __PATH__"

Tags: keycloak, saml-2.0, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, opensearch-security-plugin

After integration SAML (Keycloak) with AWS OpenSearch, getting error:

```
Error while validating SAML response in __PATH__
```

Roles are mapped as well. Error Logs and Audit Logs are enabled in CloudWatch but not showing anything other than this.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: No.. could not.  AWS Support could not fix it either. Had to give up on Keycloak integration.